# Help with Validation Rule to Enforce Prerequisite Jobs for V4S App

Tags: validation, validation-rule, nonprofit-starter-pack

I am using the Volunteers for Salesforce app with NPSP and need a validation rule that prevents volunteers from signing up for job shifts unless a prerequisite orientation has been met.

That is, only allows volunteers to sign up for Orientation unless they've taken already taken it and have its status == Completed in their contact record. After which they can sign up for any job/shift.

I've been trying different permeations of this rule and is not working how I need it to.

```
NOT((GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Campaign_Name__c = "New Volunteer Orientations") && 
     (ISPICKVAL(GW_Volunteers__Status__c, "Completed")))
```

Comment: Mike, I don't think there's enough information here to develop an answer. What object is the validation rule running on, and where is the information stored about orientation completion?

Comment: The object is Volunteer Hours (GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Hours__c).

Comment: Where is the information stored about orientation completion?

Comment: Orientation completion is stored in GW_Volunteers__Status__c field.

Comment: FYI, the best support resource for Nonprofit Success Pack is the [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com).  It's a very active community of users, consultants, and salesforce.org staff and developers.  There is a discussion group for the Volunteers for Salesforce package.